# use session from php inside laravel 4.2 controller

Tags: php, session, laravel-4

i have a php file inside the app of laravel and i used this code

```
$_SESSION["captcha"]=$code;
```

how can i used the value of this session inside laravel's controller?
Thanks

Comment: Look at `Session::set('captcha', $code)` to set it too

Comment: i used the Session::get() but i was't able to see the session. The PHP is located under the App forlder in laravel and here is the code 
`<?php
  

  session_start();
  $code=rand(10000,99999);
  $_SESSION["captcha"] = $code;
  //more codes here
?> 
`

Comment: is it possible to use `Session::set()` on a php file under the App folder?